# How to prevent SQL injection while building dynamic SQL in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sql-injection, brakeman

I am building dynamic SQL statement and executing using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_values` since the query is bit complex(joining 3 to 4 tables with couple of group by and select columns from multiple tables) and I need to much quicker response.
we are using the [Brakeman](http://brakemanscanner.org) security scanner for Identifying the any SQL injections,most these dynamic queries are marked as vulnerable for SQL injection.

I tried manually cleaning up the params which were used in dynamic SQL statement for single quotes using some of the Rails internal methods
Eg: for escaping(single quote) the strings I tried `sanitize_sql_for_conditions` other similar methods
But Brakeman is still Identifying them as vulnerable to SQL injection or escaping single quote alone won't solve the SQL injection issue ?

Is there a better way to handle SQL injection while building dynamic SQL ?

I am using Rails 2.3 ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Please furnish the question with what you have tried so far with the code. Also, attach the brakeman report to be clear for answering it..

Comment: Can you provide SQL?